# updating a bulleting board without manually editing the code by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to update my bulletin board that is coded in HTML and CSS without manually editing the codes. My bulletin board will post updates regarding on the upcoming events or maintenance. If I will do it manually this is the process I will check my outlook email, if there is an update I will manually put it in the source code then save.

Below is the sample code of my bulletin board

```css
#maincontainer {
width: 70%;
height: 55em;
background-color: #0175c9;
margin-left: 1.5%;
}

#upcomingActivitiesTitle {
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-size: 25pt;
font-family: arial;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
position: relative;
top: 10%;
}

#container {
width: 90%;
height: 35em;
margin-left: 5%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
top: 15%;
}

#subcontainer {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 25em;
margin: auto;
}

#patching {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
background-color: #234090;
padding: 0.1em;
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 20pt;
}

#patchingDesc {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
color: white;
font-family: arial;
}

#networkMaintenance {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
background-color: #234090;
padding: 0.1em;
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 20pt;
}

#networkMaintenanceDesc {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
color: white;
font-family: arial;
}

#container #subcontainer {
  animation: slide 17s 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {margin-top: 0;}
  10% {margin-top: -10em;}
  20% {margin-top: -17em;}
  30% {opacity: 1;}
  40% {margin-top: -33em;}
  41% {opacity: 0;}
  61% {opacity: 0;}
  62% {opacity: 1;}
  63% {margin-top: 33em;}
  80% {margin-top: 20em;}
  90% {margin-top: 10em;}
  100% {margin-top: 0;}

}
```

```html
<div id="maincontainer">
      <div id="upcomingActivitiesTitle">Upcoming Activities</div>
      <div id="container">
         <div id="subcontainer">
            <br/>
            <br/> 
            <div id="patching">Network Maintenance</div>
            <div id="patchingDesc"> 
               <b>June 17, 1:00AM to June 18, 1:00AM UTC - Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance</b></div>
            <br/> 
            <div id="networkMaintenance">Network Maintenance 2</div>
            <div id="networkMaintenanceDesc"> 
               <b></b>This June 17, 3:00AM to 6:00AM UTC - Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance</div>
            <br/> 
            <div id="networkMaintenance">Network Maintenance 3</div>
            <div id="networkMaintenanceDesc"> 
               <b>This June 17, 1:00AM to 2:00AM UTC - Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance Network Maintenance </b></div>
         </div>
      </div> 
   </div>
```

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'update'. If you mean 'scroll automatically', then you code already appears to be doing that. If you mean 'retrieve new updates without me copying and pasting', then you will need to configure **AJAX** to hook up to an endpoint, and parse the data to display the correct output. If the only place the updates come through is E-mail, then it's impossible to update it automatically.

Comment: What I mean is to retrieve new updates without copying and pasting. If it's impossible to get updates through email. can you elaborate on the AJAX part of your answer? Thanks

Comment: @ObsidianAge - Email doesn't make it impossible. Server-side code can process inbound emails.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to have users submit to you some sort of update and it automatically displays on your website, I would suggest using a MYSQL database to hold all upcoming events, and to display them on your page.

I would create a form, that when submitted, populates a table in your database with the date, title, and event description.  Then you would output this in another part of your website in a specified format.

Comment: Hi Dan, Users submits to me updates in an email form. Is there a way I can work things out here base on your answer?

Comment: I'm no expert but I don't know of a way to update a website based on an email.  I would suggest changing your form to populate a database in MySQL, instead of sending an email. So this is basically a system in which users are posting 'comments' correct?

Comment: Or I suppose you could set up a rather messy system using an array to hold the comments and add to the array the body of every email that is sent to you from your form. But that will be a long array and you would need a way to delete past comments as well.  Either way you will need to use PHP in addition to HTML and CSS

Comment: Thanks Dan, I will try to do that.